# Operation with two identities?

Tags: binary-operations

I have read that an operation can have at most one identity and fully understand the proof, however what if I define an operation $*$ on $\mathbb Q$ as follows?

$x*y=|x \times y|$,  $\forall x,y \in \mathbb Q$

Surely both $1$ and $-1$ are identities?  Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: What does $xy$ mean for an abstract set?  If, say, you meant to assume that $S\in \mathbb Q^*$ or such, then using your operation $-1*-1=1$, so $-1$ is not an identity.

Comment: You can't have more than one identity because $e_1\star e_2$ would have to be both $e_1$ and $e_2$.

Comment: If $x\lt0$ then the equation $x*y=x$ has no solution, so your operation has no neutral element at all.

Answer (score 1):

Note that neither $1$ nor $-1$ is an identity. We have that:

$$(-1)*(-1) = \;\mid 1 \mid\; = 1 \quad \quad (-1)*(1) = \;\mid -1 \mid\; = 1$$